When does getting 2 yellow cards in the same match not equal red?
Aston Villa managed to win from Lille and place for the half final of the Conference League. There was something odd about this match though: goalie Emiliano Martínez got 2 yellow cards yet was not send off the field by the referee. Usually, 2 yellow cards in the same match equal a red. Why didn't it this time?

This is the second duplicate today for the same situation. Please use the search functionality and review recent questions before posting a self-answered Q&A, especially in popular tags where it has likely been done already.

When looking at fouls and penalties, Law 12 of the International Football Association Board (IFAB) - Fouls and Misconduct is the first place to check. And this lists:

A player, substitute or substituted player who commits any of the following offences is sent off:
...
receiving a second caution in the same match

Which includes getting a second yellow card. Getting 2 yellow cards in the same match effectively gets you send off the field.
However, Law 10 (specifically 10.3 Penalties (penalty shoot-out)) has an interesting blurb that's basically providing an exception to the usual rules:

warnings and cautions issued to players and team officials during the match are not carried forward into penalties (penalty shoot-out).

Effectively, earning a yellow card before the shootouts does not count once you've hit the shootouts. At least, not for the purpose of being send off the field. That's what happened here, the second yellow card was handed out during the shootouts. And, apparently, this isn't the first time this goalie managed to get away with it.
